# Are the following tool versions incompatible with each other?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am encountering this issue for quiet some time and I have also checked other solutions but they are not working for me.

I am using `firebase` version 11.0.2,`google play services` version 42,`Android sdk` tools version 26.0.2,`Android sdk platform tools` version 26.0.0 and `emulator` version 26.1.2.

`build.gradle`file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig
            {
                applicationId "com.mobility.mobilityindia"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2"
    compile "com.android.support:design:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`Logcat`

```
07-12 14:39:29.816 2372-2372/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-12 14:39:29.820 2372-2372/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-12 14:39:30.391 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mobility.mobilityindia-1/lib/x86
07-12 14:39:30.949 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
07-12 14:39:30.950 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
07-12 14:39:31.047 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Collection enabled
07-12 14:39:31.047 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: App package, google app id: com.mobility.mobilityindia, 1:308094300316:android:8bb92942b462bf39
07-12 14:39:31.048 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.mobility.mobilityindia
07-12 14:39:31.048 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
07-12 14:39:31.097 2372-2393/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Verification of com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd.zze(com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd) took 122.191ms
07-12 14:39:31.153 2372-2393/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
07-12 14:39:31.192 2372-2393/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
07-12 14:39:31.197 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -631849166
07-12 14:39:31.246 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
07-12 14:39:31.251 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
07-12 14:39:31.253 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-12 14:39:31.290 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Using measurement service
07-12 14:39:31.291 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Connecting to remote service
07-12 14:39:31.295 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
07-12 14:39:31.300 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Using measurement service
07-12 14:39:31.300 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
07-12 14:39:31.486 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-12 14:39:31.521 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: onActivityCreated
07-12 14:39:31.942 2372-2383/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5869(912KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 45MB/45MB, paused 7.350ms total 78.784ms
07-12 14:39:31.986 2372-2383/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 195(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 8% free, 45MB/49MB, paused 7.751ms total 39.084ms
07-12 14:39:32.943 2372-2383/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 53MB/53MB, paused 7.772ms total 45.250ms
07-12 14:39:33.041 2372-2383/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 78(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 53MB/57MB, paused 6.114ms total 95.568ms
07-12 14:39:33.068 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-12 14:39:33.071 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
07-12 14:39:33.101 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Using measurement service
07-12 14:39:33.101 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
07-12 14:39:33.202 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
07-12 14:39:34.023 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-12 14:39:34.028 2372-2420/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-12 14:39:34.028 2372-2420/com.mobility.mobilityindia D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-12 14:39:34.029 2372-2420/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-12 14:39:34.029 2372-2420/com.mobility.mobilityindia D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-12 14:39:34.049 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 14:39:34.738 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 14:39:35.049 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
07-12 14:39:35.050 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
07-12 14:39:35.059 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Long monitor contention with owner pool-2-thread-1 (2396) at boolean android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)(Binder.java:-2) waiters=0 in int com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, boolean) for 1.936s
07-12 14:39:35.080 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
07-12 14:39:35.080 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
07-12 14:39:35.081 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/system/fake-libs:/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/system/lib:/vendor/lib for namespace 0xabf7b090
07-12 14:39:35.207 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
07-12 14:39:35.468 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
07-12 14:39:35.469 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:11 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tagmanager:0
07-12 14:39:35.469 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.tagmanager
07-12 14:39:35.513 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
07-12 14:39:35.513 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:0
07-12 14:39:35.538 2372-2396/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to load crash reporting
                                                                         com.google.android.gms.internal.mn: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ml.zzFk(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzFi(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                          Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.ml.zzFk(Unknown Source) 
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzFi(Unknown Source) 
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
07-12 14:39:35.539 2372-2398/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FirebaseCrash: Failed waiting for crash api to load.
                                                                         java.lang.InterruptedException
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1036)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1327)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:249)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzFc(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.crash.zza.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
07-12 14:39:35.591 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.
07-12 14:39:36.868 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
07-12 14:39:36.868 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 1279ms
07-12 14:39:36.869 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8694756223472310512}]
07-12 14:39:36.973 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Using measurement service
07-12 14:39:36.973 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Connecting to remote service
07-12 14:39:36.977 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
07-12 14:39:36.982 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 75134
07-12 14:39:36.983 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
07-12 14:39:36.983 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
07-12 14:39:36.983 2372-2372/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
07-12 14:39:36.983 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
07-12 14:39:36.984 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
07-12 14:39:36.984 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
07-12 14:39:36.984 2372-2415/com.mobility.mobilityindia V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 0
07-12 14:39:37.636 2372-2379/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.119ms
07-12 14:39:57.704 2372-2379/com.mobility.mobilityindia W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.922ms
```

Comment: Is your gradle build happening while online or offline?

Comment: yes, use Google Repository 54 to build in 11.0.2.

Comment: My gradle build is online

Comment: @AniruddhParihar My google repository is 55. Is it required to change it to 54 and if yes then how do I change it to 54?

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator?

Comment: @RohanStark Yes I am running it on emulator version 26.1.2

Comment: @SagarKhuteta : no need it.

Comment: you should not use both dependency at same app like compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2"

if you are applying compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2"  then no need to apply this compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that the `firebase(11.0.2)` and `google play services` were not compatible as the `google play services` was not updated.Even if I went to `Settings`->`SDK Manager`->`SDK Tools` and updated `google play Services`,the latest version was `google play services(10.9.3)` and it still was incompatible.

So I ran the app on my own Smartphone and it worked for me,as the `google play services(11.0.55)` was already there on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 10298470
```

This seems to be the key error. It occurs when the version of Google play services on the emulator is not the same as the one in your app's `build.gradle`. From the error, it is clear that the emulator is running version 10.2.9, while you've listed version 11.0.2 in your gradle.

To solve this, try and change the versions of the following to 10.2.9 :-

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2"
```

Or, if it's possible, then update to an emulator that uses the required version of Google play services.

Comment: I am getting the following errors by changing the version to 10.2.9    Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.9 Install repository and sync proj                                                            
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-auth:10.2.9           Install repository and sync proj

Comment: That is happening because version 11.0.2 is already installed in your Android Studio. And that is the right way to go, because 11.0.2 is the latest one. So, instead of downgrading to 10.2.9, run your code on an emulator that has play services 11.0.2 so that it's compatible with your version.

Comment: Try Genymotion.